# How can I capture emails without creating customer accounts?

Tags: customer, email, email-reminders

A lot of the activity on our Magento store (eyewear) will involve active customer engagement (entering Rx info) and I believe users will be willing to enter their email, but they will bounce if requested to create password.

Is there a Magento best practice to capturing emails like this? I want the ability to follow up on their abandon cart (or abandon Rx) and provide discount, etc.

Comment: I've been thinking a bit about this myself as well.  Have you had a chance to work on it yet?

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be: If customer is not logged in, listen for the add to cart event and ask for "email address to associate with this order" and save it to the quote. This was you could both use this information for sending reminders but also pre-populate the login/register {email} field for them. It also might be smart to clear this info if/when the customer logs in.

Comment: Thanks, this is the direction that I hoped for. I've created some modules, but never touched the quote. I know starting on new Magento topics can be confusing, do you have any good article that clearly explains modifying the quote?

Comment: @kevando should be pretty straight forward.  Try a `$quote->setCustomerEmail()`.  Also you should mark ryaan's answer as correct.